# BlobServiceClient object has no attribute `exists`

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created an azure pipeline. Added a task to download the file from blobStorage.

**But I am getting the following error:**

> ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
> ERROR: 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'exists'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 658, in execute
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 721, in _run_jobs_serially
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 713, in _run_job
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/**init**.py", line 385, in new_handler
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/**init**.py", line 385, in new_handler
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/_exception_handler.py", line 17, in file_related_exception_handler
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 692, in _run_job
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 328, in **call**
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/operations/blob.py", line 363, in storage_blob_download_batch
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/util.py", line 16, in collect_blobs
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/util.py", line 16, in 
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/storage/util.py", line 31, in collect_blob_objects
> AttributeError: 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'exists'
> To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
> ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.\

**Inline script written in Task:**

> az storage blob download-batch --destination $(build.sourcesDirectory) --pattern $(jmxfile) -s $(jmeter-storagecontainer) --account-name $(az-storageaccount) --account-key '$(az-accountkey)' --connection-string '$(az-connstring)'

I have verified all the variable values are correct & the jmxfile pattern is also correct.

Any idea, why getting this `BlobServiceClient Object has no attribute 'exists'` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error **"BlobServiceClient Object has no attribute 'exists'"** usually occurs if you are using ***az cli latest version*** and executing **`az storage blob download-batch`** command.

- To resolve the error, try using **`az storage blob download`** as a workaround.
- Otherwise, try ***installing the previous version*** by uninstalling Azure cli latest version.
- Make sure to delete all the ***dependencies*** of latest version while doing the above step.
- Please note that **`--pattern`** parameter only supports four cases

[image]

- Please note that there is a bug dealing with full blob name in **latest CLI**.

Please check the below **GitHub blog** which confirms the above issue:

[Latest az cli fails to run download-batch command · Issue #21966 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21966)